# Java Applet Game Design : Keyboard focus

Tags: java, swing, applet, keyboard, focus

I had posted this in a wrong place (`GameDev`) and got no response there. So I'm posting it again here.

I'm making an applet game and it is rendering, the game loop is running, the animations are updating, but the keyboard input is not working. Here's an SSCCE.

```
public class Game extends JApplet implements Runnable {

    public void init(){
        // Initialize the game when called by browser
        setFocusable(true);
        requestFocus();
        requestFocusInWindow();  // Always returning false
        GInput.install(this);    // Install the input manager for this class
        new Thread(this).start();
    }

    public void run(){
        startGameLoop();
    }

}
```

And Here's the GInput class.

```
public class GInput implements KeyListener {

    public static void install(Component c){
        new GInput(c);
    }

    public GInput(Component c){
        c.addKeyListener(this);
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e){
        System.out.println("A key has been pressed");
    }

    ......

}
```

This is my GInput class. When run as an applet, it doesn't work and when I add the Game class to a frame, it works properly.

Thanks

Solved now. See my solution

Comment: The page at GameDev is http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/34555/java-applet-game-design-no-keyboard-focus

Comment: Since it works as a frame, the best approach is to launch the frame from a link using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).

Comment: I don't do applets, so I can't say for sure what the problem is, but you can get around focus issues by using Key Bindings instead of a KeyListener. Also your SSCCE does not comply with the SSCCE specification. We cannot run it nor test it.

Comment: I know I could do it through web start but I wan't to learn to program as an applet because this is going to be in my game engine

Comment: *"wan't to learn to program as an applet because this is going to be in my game engine"*  Ummm.. sure, OK.  I have no idea why that rules out using a frame launched using JWS.  Can you explain?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I've added only the crux of the problem. The full game class can be read here. https://code.google.com/p/game-engine-for-java/source/browse/src/com/gej/core/Game.java

Comment: I think most would prefer to see a compliant sscce.

Comment: @AndrewThompson This is just to add another feature so that it also can give scope for web game development. And moreover, certain OS's like JNode cannot run programs using JWS

Comment: *"certain OS's like JNode cannot run programs using JWS"*  Huh..  never heard of [JNode OS](http://www.jnode.org/) before today.  But something I *have* heard a lot of is "this applet does not work in X version of Y browser on Z OS - but gee it works if launched by JWS".  JWS will give greater overall coverage of machines, today, than applets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that I have two options,

- Use JWS
- Don't make an applet mode

Now I had tried to make a new class called `GApplet`. It loads a game into a new JFrame which worked from the applet. Now I can access the fullscreen mode from web too. Here's a link to the class.

[The `GApplet` class](http://pastebin.com/f4cjQBs6)

And now it's working like the webstart and is actually an applet.

Answer (score 4):

One possible solution is to use the JApplet's contentPane, to set the focus on it rather than on the JApplet itself. But my preference is to use Key Bindings instead. You may need to use a Swing Timer for this to work:

My SSCCE:

```
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;

import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class AppletKeyListen extends JApplet {
   @Override
   public void init() {
      try {
         SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
               setFocusable(true);

               int timerDelay = 100;
               Timer myTimer = new Timer(timerDelay , new ActionListener() {

                  @Override
                  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                     boolean focusObtained = requestFocusInWindow();
                     System.out.println("focusObtained for JApplet: " + focusObtained);

                     Container contentPane = getContentPane();
                     contentPane.setFocusable(true);

                     focusObtained = contentPane.requestFocusInWindow();
                     System.out.println("focusObtained for contentPane: " + focusObtained);


                  }
               });
               myTimer.setRepeats(false);
               myTimer.start();
//               boolean focusObtained = requestFocusInWindow();
//               System.out.println("focusObtained: " + focusObtained);
//               
//               Container contentPane = getContentPane();
//               contentPane.setFocusable(true);
//               
//               focusObtained = contentPane.requestFocusInWindow();
//               System.out.println("focusObtained: " + focusObtained);

            }
         });
      } catch (InvocationTargetException | InterruptedException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: But the game is itself programmed in the JApplet. How can I use the content pane? Could you please explain a bit..

Comment: @SriHarshaChilakapati: see edit and code, and ***yes***, that's where Key Bindings work **best**.

Comment: But it's told frequently that timer is a bad implementation for games. Is there another way.. please

Comment: @sri: WTF? Where did this "rule" come in? Too crazy. I think youg're confusing issues as this has nothing to do with a game loop which is likely what you're talking about.

Comment: I had seen it in many posts. They say that the timer isn't implemented the same on all the platforms

Comment: Also requesting focus on the content pane doesn't work for me

Comment: @Sri: again you're greatly confusing concepts. Again, I recommend that you use Key Bindings for most of your keyboard interactions.

Comment: @SriHarshaChilakapati if you look carefully at the posted code, you would see that the `Timer` in this case is only used to execute certain code after a slight delay on the Event Dispatch Thread. This has nothing to do with using a `Timer` to update your game state

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels See http://www.java-gaming.org/index.php?topic=24220.0 It says we should not use timer

Comment: @Sri: that talks about not using a Timer for a game loop. As has been told to you now three times, this has *nothing* to do with my recommendations since we are not discussing game loops here, and my timer is a non-repeating Timer. Also the recommendations in that link aren't all that great, but again it has nothing to do with using a Timer for the purposes above. Please read the whole link and understand it fully before blindly applying poorly understood concepts.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Does game loops stop input??? When I've removed the game loop, and repainting constantly, the input works...

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels What if the applet mode launched a window?? It can also access fullscreen mode.. (like yoyogames does)

Comment: Game loops if used incorrectly can stop input, since if the looping is done on the Swing event thread (also known as the Event Dispatch Thread or EDT) it can tie up this thread preventing it from doing its important work of drawing the GUI and interacting with the user.

Comment: But now I had decided to use the fullscreen exclusive mode or windowed mode and let them start from the applet. Wouldn't that be right??? It's working on my system.

Comment: I don't know as I don't do applets.

Answer (score 1):

If you're running in a browser, you probably need to click on the applet to give it focus. For security reasons most browsers won't let an applet just grab the keyboard focus without the user clicking it.

So, I would add a mouse listener instead of doing the focus grabbing directly in `init()`:

```
addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
   public void onMousePress(MouseEvent e) {
      requestFocus();
   }
});
```

Comment: If the applet does not have focus, it is not for security reasons.

Comment: I have included only the basic template of the classes. The full GInput class can be found here. https://code.google.com/p/game-engine-for-java/source/browse/src/com/gej/input/GInput.java

Comment: Also tried using a focus listener too but no solution still :(

Comment: OK, but notice that your mouse listener doesn't request focus. I've always found that to get key focus to an applet I need to have it start with a "Click to begin" message and then have the user actually click it.